# Need to Display only one Object in my list view (Only title ) in my case

Tags: java, android, listview, object, android-arrayadapter

I am working with a Listview where I get a Json response which I parse using Gson and the response contains title, body and images. For my list view I need to display on titles I am doing the following:

```
Articles[] testCase = gson.fromJson(Bundlekey, Articles[].class);


            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList(); 
            ArrayList<Articles> lst = new ArrayList<Articles>();
            for (int i = 0; i < testCase.length; i++) {
                list.add(testCase[i].getTitle());
                list.add(testCase[i].getBody());
                list.add(testCase[i].getImages());

                lst.add(testCase[i]);
                Log.e("DONE", testCase[i].getTitle().toString());   
            }

            final ArrayAdapter<Articles> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Articles>(
                    activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst);
            activity.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I am defining my Articles class as this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Articles implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8359220892008313080L;
    public List<Articles> results;

    @SerializedName("body")
    private String body;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("images")
    private List<Images> images;

    /*public Articles() {
        this.body = body;
        this.title = title;
        this.images = images;

    }*/

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public List<Images> getImages() {
        return images ;
    }

    public void setImages(List<Images> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("***** Articles  *****\n");
        sb.append("BODY=" + getBody() + "\n");
        sb.append("TITLE=" + getTitle() + "\n");
        sb.append("IMAGES=" + getImages() + "\n");
        sb.append("*****************************");

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

My list is showing with title and body and images all mixed in, I have tried workarounds but I don't seem to really understand what would be the next in order to solve this problem which is displaying only the titles in the listview.

Any suggestion/solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapter `ArrayAdapter<Articles> adapter` is using toString of `Articles` to show row into list. As you have used all three attributes into `toString()` of `Articles` class, this is showing all three attributes, as you said.

---

You need to use only `title` into `toString()`, then it will show only title as list row.

Replace `toString()` code with

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // Return only title from this method to print title into list row.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("TITLE=" + getTitle() + "\n");
    return sb.toString();
    // OR
    // return getTitle(); // Better is to return this.title;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What @Pankaj Kumar said is right. And in case you don't want to mess with the structure of your `Articles` class you could store just the titles into a new `String[]` and use that to initialize the `ArrayAdapter`

That is, after you have populated your `lst` containing all the `Articles`:

```
String[] titles = new String[lst.size()];
int i = 0;
for(Articles article: lst) {
    titles[i] = article.getTitle();
    i++;
}
```

Then initialize your `ArrayAdapter` with `titles` as,

```
ArrayAdapter<Articles> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Articles>(
                activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
activity.setListAdapter(adapter);
```